# Force yes in m-a prepare on Debian

Tags: bash, shell, debian

I'm trying to write a simple shell script to configure my wifi on Debian.

Steps:

1. Install dependencies
2. Run `m-a prepare` to configure modules

My problem is run the step 2 forcing it to use yes. When I run `m-a prepare` the command ask for install kernel-headers. But I need to force without asking to install.

Is there a way to force this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a program called `yes` which just repeatedly outputs `y`.

```
yes | m-a prepare
```

should work.

`yes` exists for the very purpose of automatically answering those prompts in scripts, with `y` every time. Of course, it only works if the program only asks questions that can be answer by `y`.

Comment: works fine. thank you!